# Changing the word 'post' to 'project' in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, function, post

For my users, the word 'post' does not reflect what they are actually adding when submitting a 'post'. For them, it's a project.

I'd like to change the word 'post' everywhere it appears in the admin area to be 'project', is there a function I can add to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to edit core WP files Jessica, I'd like this to be changed in my theme via functions.php ideally.

Comment: The theme doesn't apply to the admin.

Comment: OK I'm sure there is another method other than editing the core WP files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('gettext',  'change_post_to_project');
add_filter('ngettext',  'change_post_to_project');

function change_post_to_project($translated) {
     $translated = str_ireplace('Post',  'Project',  $translated);  
     return $translated;
}
```